# Basket variance with correlation 1

Tags: volatility, portfolio, basket, dispersion

I'm reading the famous [nuclear phynance](https://www.nuclearphynance.com/User%20Files/2/Dispersion%20-%20A%20guide%20for%20the%20clueless%201.1.pdf) primer on dispersion trading and finding difficulty in understanding the author's simplification for the variance of a basket with correlation 1. See below:

[image]

I can't see where the second formula comes from. Let's assume we have a 2-asset portfolio and $\rho = 1$. We would have:

$$\sigma_{Basket}^2 = w_1^2\sigma_1^2 + w_2^2\sigma_2^2 + 2w_1w_2\sigma_1\sigma_2$$

which, recognizing this as the expansion of $(w_1\sigma_1 + w_2\sigma_2)^2$ and generalizing for $n$ assets (assuming again that $\rho = 1$), we can say:

$$\sigma_{Basket}^2 = (\sum_{i=1}^n w_i\sigma_i)^2$$

From this point on though, I have no idea how the author could simplify down to the final formula. They are not numerically equivalent. Maybe I am misreading, or perhaps it's just a math hurdle, but any explanation of what the author is attempting to say here would be wonderful. Thank you!

Comment: There's most likely a typo in the original text.